# How to use substitute method in Z3 to replace a variable to True its not working and it replaces with ζ1 and also simplify method doesn't work?

Tags: z3, z3py

This is the following code . I also tried to convert it into Bool and BoolRef but here also it didn't work:-

```
print(A)
substitute(A, (Var[0], Bool(True) )) # where Var[0] = x_0_2

Output:-
And(And(And(And(x_0_3, Not(x_0_2)), Not(x_0_1)), Not(x_0_0)),
And(And(And(x_1_3 == x_0_0, x_1_2 == x_0_3),
        x_1_1 == x_0_2),
    x_1_0 == x_0_1))
    x_0_3 ∧ ¬ζ1 ∧ ¬x_0_1 ∧ ¬x_0_0 ∧ x_1_3 = x_0_0 ∧ x_1_2 = x_0_3 ∧ x_1_1 = ζ1 ∧ x_1_0 = x_0_1
```

Comment: Please do not post segments of your code, it's impossible to debug by others. Post a minimal-complete example that people can run on their own. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alias I'm new here and I will update the question . But there's a general question which doesnt need any code snippets which is if you can tell me how to replace some variables with true in boolean expression and then simplify it using z3 theorem prover. It would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack-overflow works the best if you post code that people can run on their own; without seeing other parts of what you are doing it's impossible for other people to figure out what else might cause issues in your code.

Having said that, here's how you'd substitute `True` for a variable:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Bools('x y')
expr = And(x, Or(y, And(x, y)))
print expr
expr2 = substitute(expr, (x, BoolVal(True)))
print expr2
print simplify(expr2)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
And(x, Or(y, And(x, y)))
And(True, Or(y, And(True, y)))
y
```

which shows the effect of the substitution and the further simplification of the expression. Note the use of the term `BoolVal(True)` to get access to the constant value `True` as a boolean expression.